# Сравнение картинок

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Как в Delphi сравнить две картинки? Или есть какие-то другие способы решения этой задачи?

Задача:

> Имеется поле хаотично окрашенное в разные цвета на нём через определённое время появляется объект (картинка). Необходимо найти координаты этого объекта.

Comment: ну самое простое, что я придумал - сравнивать по размеру =) все зависит от реализации программы, как туда добавляются картинки, в каком виде, чем отличаются...

Comment: Ну раз уже есть совет сравнивать по размеру картинки, то может всетаки более правильным было бы сравнивать по хешам файлов?

Answer (score 1):

Эту задачу можно решить довольно просто. Я не знаю полного условия зачачи.
Вообщем, если картинка слишком большая, например больше 200х200, то картинку,
а точнее **BitMap-объект** придется масштабировать с помощью функции StretchDraw, 
например до размеров 100х100. Если картинку не масштабировать, то все ресурсы ЦП
будут направлены на сканирование картинки. Так, как сканировать?
Предлагаю сканировать каждый пиксель битмапа вот так:

```
> var bmp:TbitMap;
> begin
> bmp.Canvas.Pixels[x,y];   //этот метод возвращает цвет пикселя в цифровом виде
> ...
```

Ну, а далее все зависит от того, насколько развито твое мышление!

Надеюсь, ты догадался, что надо будет создать двумерную матрицу размером
width X height самого изображения и далее записывать туда значение каждого
пикселя, полученное методом **Canvas.Pixels[x,y];**.
Потом заводишь таймер и постоянно сканируешь битмап на изменения.
Удачи!

Comment: `bmp.Canvas.Pixels` очень медленный. Смотрите в сторону вытаскивания данных из картинки через `Scanline` в локальный массиви работу с данными уже в нём.